# Google analytics Event tracking code (radio buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, radio-button

I'd like to track a form on my real-estate website. The difficulty is that I have 3 radio buttons (only one can be chosen) and I don't know how to link the button chosen to the event that will be send after the customer has clicked on "Sent" (envoyé).

See the form on the bot left and corner  here :

http://www.ajp-immobilier.com/annonces/achat/appartement/bordeaux-33/102071295.htm

So my code, would be :

```
$('.btn-send-contact ').on('click',function() {
ga("send", "event", " Page Detail Annonces " , "click" ,"Contact envoyé",);
```

... but what should I add to indicate inside GA that this event is linked to the chosen radio button? Otherwise I know that the event is "sent" but I don't know for what button...

I apologize if it's not clear enough, I'am not a developer nor a native english speaker.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/y79oga9v/

Comment: Kinda Adam, your method is very interesting. Schematically, what I am looking for is :

If the visitor clicked on "radio button", and if the "send form" button is clicked after that, then send an form validation event which precise the name of the radio button.

I hope is clearer this way :) (And I take your code anyway, will be very helpful)

Comment: Also Adam, can I do something like that :

https://jsfiddle.net/y79oga9v/4/     . 

I just took your code and applied mine to it. Don't know if it works but that's part of the idea.

Indeed, the form validation event "Contact envoyé" will be send if the visitor clicks on the "Envoyer un message" button but I will not know "what" kind of buttons would have been "checked" by the visitor. 

Do I have to precise it directly like that (see below) for each radio button events ?

ga("send", "event", " Page Detail Annonces " , "click" ,"Visiter ce bien",);

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to capture the text of the particular radio button clicked and then send that as the event label:

```
$('.btn-send-contact').click(function(){
   $('#form-contact-agence input[name="type-message"]:checked').each(function(){
       console.log($(this).closest('.radio.inline').text().trim());
       var label = $(this).closest('.radio.inline').text().trim();
       ga("send", "event", " Page Detail Annonces" , "click", label);
   });
})
```

Just note that this does not do form validation, so whenever the "Envoyer un message" button is clicked, it will send the event. But at least this shows you how you can get that text value of the selected radio button.

Comment: That is definitely what I am aiming to achieve :)

If I understand correctly, if a visitor clicks on the "envoyer un message" button, it will send the event even if the form is not filled entirely/at all?

Should I add on the top of that a "form submit" (I read that somewhere) in order to "force" the validation of the form?

If I capture the button text and put it inside the EventLabel in GA, it could be a way to make my dashboards clearer and easier to read anyway so that is a good tip :)

Thanks for your help